# Regular expressions for CloudWatch alarms

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have microservice that sends some custom metrics to AWS CloudWatch. Metric name consists of package name and some other data. For example `gauge.com.example.test.time` and `gauge.com.example.test2.time` and so on

Now I need to create some alarms based on this metrics. Is it possible to specify some reqular expression in metric name field when you create CloudWatch alarm instead of manual creation of separate alarm for each metric?

I tried such things: `gauge.com.example..time` `gauge.com.example.*.time` `gauge.com.example.(\w).time` and many other things but without success.

Comment: good question but I do not believe you can do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible. From [Creating Amazon CloudWatch Alarms](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/AlarmThatSendsEmail.html)

> You can create a CloudWatch alarm that watches a **single** metric.

Answer (score 3):

It is now possible to create aws alarms based on a Metric Math Expression.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Create-alarm-on-metric-math-expression.html

[image: math expression]